Difference between super:: and SUPERDISPATCH
What is the difference between for example:
SetPowerState(powerFlags, SUPERDISPATCH);
and
super::SetPowerState(powerFlags);
The documentation for SetPowerState says that super:: should be called at the end of the override of SetPowerState, but if I use that my driver crashes.
The documentation of SUPERDISPATCH says that it should not be used for methods marked with the LOCALONLYmacro.
SetPowerState is marked with the LOCAL macro, which is defined to a different attribute than LOCALONLY.
